# optimize looping mysql result codeigniter mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Get the results from follow table max(date)

leads  table

```
id   name   
75943    name1  
82501    name2
```

lead_follow_up

```
id lead_id       msg      date       updated 
1     75943      msg1    1438930800  1438884890
2     75943      msg2    1416459600  1415901523
3     82501      msg1    1454713200  1454485087
4     82501      msg1    1439362800  1438564891
```

using the following query i get result

$today_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon, $day-1, $year);

```
SELECT *  FROM (`lead_follow_up`) LEFT JOIN `leads` ON `leads`.`id` = `lead_follow_up`.`lead_id` WHERE `date` <=  $today_date GROUP BY `lead_follow_up`.`lead_id` ORDER BY `lead_follow_up`.`date` DESC
```

from the above query i get array `$previou`

```
 $previou=    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [lead_id] => 75943
            [date] => 1438930800
            [updated_on] => 1438884890
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [lead_id] => 75943
            [date] => 1416459600
            [updated_on] => 1415901523
        ),
     [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [lead_id] => 75943
            [date] => 1416459600
            [updated_on] => 1415901523
        ),....etc

);

foreach($previou as $key => $p):
    $q = "SELECT `id` FROM (`lead_follow_up`) WHERE `lead_id` = '".$p->id."' AND `date` > '".$p->date."' ORDER BY `updated_on` DESC ";
    if(!$this->db->query($q)){
        $previouData[$key] = $p;
        $pCount++;
    }
endforeach;
```

What I'm really expecting to see is data like

```
id lead_id  name    msg
 1  75943 name1     msg1
```

any help to optimize this in single query

Comment: do you want to merge the two queries as a one query @bala

Comment: yes i need to get data in single query @Karthik...

Comment: so you want only one result of id 1?

Comment: Can you please explain more about what result your are expecting?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(leads.id), lead_follow_up.lead_id, leads.name, lead_follow_up.msg  FROM (lead_follow_up) LEFT JOIN leads ON leads.id = lead_follow_up.lead_id WHERE date <= $today_date GROUP BY lead_follow_up.lead_id ORDER BY lead_follow_up.date ASC

Comment: where u checked SELECT `id` FROM (`lead_follow_up`) WHERE `lead_id` = '".$p->id."' AND `date` > '".$p->date."' ORDER BY `updated_on` DESC

Comment: No this will not be required. Because you need the date which is greater than today am I right?

Comment: this is another condition i want to check, thats y im using loop

Comment: Yes this condition will be satisfied on join table condition "ON leads.id = lead_follow_up.lead_id"

Comment: from result array i want to check  SELECT id FROM (lead_follow_up) WHERE lead_id = '".$p->id."' AND date > '".$p->date."' ORDER BY updated_on DESC

Comment: the "ON leads.id = lead_follow_up.lead_id" will be joining the tables only if the lead_id matches. So their is not point of checking it again.

Comment: u r not read question properly

Comment: Please explain the concept how you want to get the result?

Comment: As far as my understanding you need the details of lead_id which is greater date than all.

Comment: yes, refer that foreach() function u get an idea,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102546/discussion-between-karthik-n-and-bala).